# Reference request - Overview over established solar thermal desalination technologies

Tags: water, solar-thermal, seawater

I'm looking for an overview of established [solar thermal desalination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_desalination) technologies. The wiki page is remarkably poor on sources.

"Established" means there is a large scale plant (>50 m³/d) or many small scale plants with several years 'uptime'. The overview should include the working principles/principle construction and basic performance metrics (throughput in conditions). Anything written in this century is recent enough.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of papers published between 2011 and 2016:

- Ranjan, K. R., and S. C. Kaushik. 2013. ‘[Energy, Exergy and Thermo-Economic Analysis of Solar Distillation Systems: A Review](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S136403211300470X)’. Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews 27 (November): 709–23. doi:10.1016/j.rser.2013.07.025.
- Velmurugan, V., and K. Srithar. 2011. ‘[Performance Analysis of Solar Stills Based on Various Factors Affecting the productivity—A Review](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364032110003527)’. Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews 15 (2): 1294–1304. doi:10.1016/j.rser.2010.10.012.
- Sharon, H., and K. S. Reddy. 2015. ‘[A Review of Solar Energy Driven Desalination Technologies](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364032114007758)’. Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews 41 (January): 1080–1118. doi:10.1016/j.rser.2014.09.002.
- Esfahani, Iman Janghorban, Jouan Rashidi, Pouya Ifaei, and ChangKyoo Yoo. 2016. ‘[Efficient Thermal Desalination Technologies with Renewable Energy Systems: A State-of-the-Art Review](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Changkyoo_Yoo/publication/291384784_Efficient_thermal_desalination_technologies_with_renewable_energy_systems_A_state-of-the-art_review/links/56c178e808ae2f498ef9b82a.pdf)’. Korean Journal of Chemical Engineering 33 (2): 351–87. doi:10.1007/s11814-015-0296-3.
- El-Sebaii, A. A., and E. El-Bialy. 2015. ‘[Advanced Designs of Solar Desalination Systems: A Review](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1364032115004311)’. Renewable and Sustainable Energy Reviews 49 (September): 1198–1212. doi:10.1016/j.rser.2015.04.161.

If you can't find the full text, you can use [Sci-Hub](https://scihub22266oqcxt.onion.link/), where you can search by DOI.